# How can I activate kml file in Umbraco 7.2.8?

Tags: kml, umbraco7

I am developing a new site in Umbraco 7.2.8.

I need display google maps in the site, I have the kml file with all information and the js file to process the information, but when I load the file in front-end I have the error "GET [http://myserver/Scripts/agencias.kml?*=1443806128026*](http://myserver/Scripts/agencias.kml?_=1443806128026) 404 Not Found"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - [http://myserver/Scripts/agencias.kml?=1443806128026](http://myserver/Scripts/agencias.kml?_=1443806128026)"

How I can activate or display the kml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the .kml extension to web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".kml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```